# Calling webservice with Windows Authentication in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, windows-authentication

I am trying to call a webservice (Exchange EWS) with Windows Authentication in Windows Phone 8.
Adding the service reference worked and after manually configuring the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig with:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEWS" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
          </security>            
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://servername/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEWS"
          contract="ServiceReference1.ExchangeServicePortType"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IEWS" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And calling it with:

```
    ServiceReference1.ExchangeServicePortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.ExchangeServicePortTypeClient();            
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"username";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = @"password";            
    client.GetRoomListsCompleted += client_GetRoomListsCompleted;
    client.GetRoomListsAsync(new ServiceReference1.GetRoomListsType());
```

I get

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (401) Unauthorized. 
In Silverlight, a 404 response code may be reported even when the service sends a different error code.
```

error.
I tried all kinds of configuration changes.
The most obvious one

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
```

leads to

```
Unrecognized element 'security' in service reference configuration. Note that only a subset of the Windows Communication Foundation configuration functionality is available in Silverlight.
```

Now I start to believe (i can't bring up a google result to confirm that) there is no possibility to use windows authentication in windows phone 8 with webservices.

The only solution i found till now is using and building/parsing my own soap content

```
    WebClient c = new WebClient();
    c.BaseAddress = "https://servername/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
    c.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

Any Ideas?
Any Help on this?
Any link which validates my assumption?

Is there any source example of handling soap requests in c# without using a proxy class?

Comment: WP8 looks like it is using a version of silverlight.  In the past I have been able to get Silverlight 4 to work with WCF - Following similar instructions to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd744835(v=vs.95).aspx.   However this was based on the Silverlight client being hosted in the browser and Silverlight using the browsers authentication mechanism to validate the client on the server.

Comment: Yeah, found that link too, but could no come up with a methode of using that in windows phone. Any ideas?